# Using jquery-localize for bilingual Shopify store

Tags: jquery, localization, shopify

I'm trying to use [jquery-localize](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize) to make a bilingual (pt-en) [Shopify](http://shopify.com) store. Jquery-localize is working (translating the strings in the default language - pt - to the client browser language - mine is en). I need:

1. the shop in the default language (pt) for portuguese and
   brazilian customers;
2. the shop in english for international customers (en, es, fr, de, ja, etc.)
3. a drop-down list for the customer to choose in which language he wants to view the store (ex. I'm portuguese but with a english browser, but I want to see the pt version of the store).

Is this possible with jquery-localize? How do I get this to work?

Thank you,

Ana Rita

Comment: If it is at all possible I would suggest doing this server side for a couple of reasons: (1) Depending on the amount of content it could be a slow thing on client machines to render a ton of DOM changes. (2) You will waste bandwidth transferring content in multiple languages.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This will be just navigation and a few more static strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a better solution for my needs was not jquery-localize but i18next:

http://jamuhl.github.com/i18next/ (website: https://www.i18next.com)

Answer (score 0):

There's another answer to this - a script I wrote for a Shopify client of mine to enable English and Greek bilingual features. It's SEO friendly, works on any Shopify theme and any two languages.

You can check it out here - http://www.affiliatewebdesigners.com/product/bilingual-javascript/